# How to insert an image in python

Tags: python, import, insert

how do you import or insert an image using python.Basically I want to know how to import an image and how to select the file and folder its in using python.

Comment: but, what you want to do with the image? Yo only want to acces to the raw image content?

Comment: Have you looked into the builtin function open?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Navigate the file system?  Open an image?  Manipulate an image?  Programmatically, or with a GUI?  You need to break down what you want to do much more and provide a concrete, answerable question.

Comment: If you want to display it, `PLY.Image.Image.show()` is practical.

Comment: please if the answer is right for your question , please make sure to accepted it as answer

Answer (score 8):

Install PIL(Python Image Library) :

then:

```
from PIL import Image
myImage = Image.open("your_image_here");
myImage.show();
```

Comment: @PMARINA What would your alternative be? Write it from scratch?

Comment: Note that you must install the `Pillow` package, not `PIL`