# Import image in python

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

hello I am a beginner in python and I have problems executing my code .
how can i fix this error with python:

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print('Content-type: text/html\r\n')
print('\r\n')

import Image, ImageDraw

import sys
import math, random
from itertools import product
from ufarray import *

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
          args = ("No module named 'Image'",)
          msg = "No module named 'Image'"
          name = 'Image'
          path = None
          with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of ModuleNotFoundError
```

Comment: show us the import part of your code

Comment: It seems you haven't got those libraries installed

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have installed [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) (the supported, open-source version of the PIL Python Image Library) and then change your import to:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
```

That should get you farther along.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
from PIL import Image
```

or else you haven't installed it yet:

```
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar Problem, this post helped me: [How to insert an image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442923/how-to-insert-an-image-in-python)

What they basically use is:

```
import Image
myImage = Image.open("your_image_here");
myImage.show();
```

For more help I would need your full code. Even after the edit it is not quite clear to me what is your code, what is the error and what you are actually trying to do.